# Gaming on 2 monitors macOS

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, macos, monitor

I want to play CS:GO or other related games on my MacOS but with 2 monitors at the same time. But the game will launch only on 1 of the monitors that I choose from the System Preferences. Any idea or knowledge about this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Surround](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/surround) / [Mosaic](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia-mosaic-technology.html) to do that, if you have a supported nVidia card or [Eyefinity](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/technologies-gaming/eyefinity) as AMD's equivalent.

However, CS GO does **not** support multiple monitors on its own, so it's at your own risk.  You would need to use 3rd party tools and you never know how VAC reacts on those things. It works, but might get you banned. Beware!

[Here](http://www.wsgf.org/mgl) is a list of games with some info about their multi monitor support.

Comment: I do not recommend to use software to manipulate CS:GO. Could end in a VAC-ban.

Comment: Although I haven't heard of anyone getting banned for using multiple screens (and the tools required to accomplish this) I don't recommend that either, that's why I didn't describe using it.

Answer (score 3):

**CS:GO is made for only one monitor.**

With two monitors your crosshair would be between the monitors... pretty hard to aim with bezels splitting up the crosshair, so it makes sense to play CS:GO on one monitor.

**What can you do:**
You can use your second monitor to show a picture of the current map for a better overview or to show a strategy-guide. (Just examples, feel free to open up what you want.)

**Other games:**
This affects a lot of games. Maybe you can find a game which supports a dual monitor setup, showing up some stats or infos on your other monitor. Just take a look at the videosettings of your game.

Comment: Oh, thanks actually but do you know any games that work with 2 monitors?

Comment: X-Plane does support multi-monitors.

Comment: some people are also playing CS:GO with 3 monitors!